# Adding data to XHTML tags

Tags: html, xhtml

My website is XHTML 1.1, and I had added 'rel' attributes to the `<li>` and `<div>` tags on my page, to store data for a jQuery script on the page.  When validating my page, I get the error: "there is no attribute 'rel'".  So, what is the best way to store arbitrary data in HTML tags?

I am working on a comments page for my website.  When a comment is entered, it is POSTed via AJAX, which returns JSON of all comments.  I then look at the 'rel' values to see which comments are already on the page, and only add the new ones.

The jQuery code works fine, it's just the 'rel' attributes don't validate.

Comment: Why don't you just return JSON of the new comment?

Comment: @Dave, I thought of that, but what if someone posted a comment between the time you opened the page, and the time you posted a comment.  I wanted all new comments to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I don't know why I even used 'rel' in the first place, I really should have used 'id' (or 'name').  I like the idea of extending XHTML to support new attributes... or I could just switch to HTML5.

Comment: You could add some sort of hash (e.g. id of the newest comment) to your form via a hidden input. Then after saving the comment(serverside) check for comments with greater id and return only these.

Comment: @Dave, that's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's not XHTML spec, you could use the data-* attributes that are included in HTML5's spec.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

If you want to remain fully XHTML 1.1 compliant, you'll need to create a schema and include its namespace in the `html` element, where the schema defines the attributes you want to use, and the elements to which they apply.

[Extending XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434450/extending-xhtml)

Comment: +1 You can start using the HTML5 Doctype today, all browser should handle this correctly.

Comment: Chosen as answer for the Extending XHTML post, that's neat.

Answer (score 1):

Since `rel` isn't valid attribute for `li`, you should use `id` instead attribute instead and it is valid there too.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't do this to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes against the spirit of XHTML to store "arbitrary" data in tags. You should use the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method instead.

Comment: Just posted the same answer and deleted it. If I understand the question correctly, the data should already be there in the HTML. If this had not to be the case then you could store the data in a variable and would not need to add it to an HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery seems to like classes as a way to store state for different html elements.

One example would be how jQuery UI Tabs use the `ui-state-active` class to define which tab is currently selected.

One benefit of this method is how easy you can select elements by the different states you are looking for.

As a reminder, you can add (virtually) as many classes to an element as you want and just separate them by spaces.

```
<li class="client_data already_added red_text etc">Bob</li>
```