# How to use data attributes in XHTML1.1 and still be valid

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to use html5 data attibutes and still have valid XHTML 1.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-test="test">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

=> There is no attribute data-test. (In W3C Validator)

OK. Try adding a custom namespace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:data="http://whatever">
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data:test="test">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Same problem.

I have looked at many of the questions on this topic on Stackoverflow. Some mention that this problem can be solved using a custom namespace. But I can't see any working examples. My attempt above isn't validating. Is this because the DOCTYPE for XHTML does not support adding custom namespaces? (Even if this could be got to work I have a new problem that for html5 data types I need my attribute to be data- and the hyphen is going to cause problems - but one step at a time).

The other way to do this is with a custom DTD. This article explains how to do that http://alistapart.com/article/customdtd - but this doesn't help me as that requires you to be using a parser that can be told what DTD to use - i.e. not a browser.

The actual case is I am making a small piece of software which outputs html which end users will plug into their sites. It uses html5 data attributes and I don't want to break their site. I want to be able to at least tell them: modify your xhtml like this and it will work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding data to XHTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670950/adding-data-to-xhtml-tags)

Comment: I've been looking at that. It seems to point to another question/answer which ends up talking about defining a custom DTD - which (while it may work) is not a solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: that's pretty much how it has to be. xhtml was a VERY strict implementation of html, and predates html5. since it predates it, there's no provision for unknown attributes like `data-*`. Basically, you're asking how to install a modern bluetooth-capable stereo in fred flintstone's car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to use html5 data attibutes and still have valid XHTML 1.1.

That is impossible.

> Some mention that this problem can be solved using a custom namespace.

You could, but then you would be writing XHTML 1.1 + SOMETHING ELSE and not XHTML 1.1.

Browsers wouldn't support it anyway, at least not through the standard APIs they provide specifically for accessing `data-*` attributes since they don't look in foreign namespaces for them.

> The other way to do this is with a custom DTD.

Then you would be writing a custom markup language you invented that was based on XHTML 1.1, and not XHTML 1.1.

---

> The actual case is I am making a small piece of software which outputs html which end users will plug into their sites. It uses html5 data attributes and I don't want to break their site. I want to be able to at least tell them: modify your xhtml like this and it will work.

I've never encountered a browser that would fall over when given invalid but well-formed XHTML.

Just write XML serialised HTML 5.

You could encourage the end users to move to HTML 5. XHTML 1.1 is a technological cul-de-sac anyway. The W3C has abandoned further work on XHTML outside of the XML serialisation of HTML 5.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I take your point that even if we can use a separate namepace the browser won't look for it there anyway. But one question: in my second code example above I believe that i have correctly extended an XML document with a namespace 'data' - why is the validator not having it? - I also accept that the correct solution is to tell my clients that the page will still display anyway.