# can I access the source xml using javascript after an xslt stylesheet is applied?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can create an HTML form from an XML instance document with an xslt stylesheet to run in a browser.  The form can modify the XML instance document and send it back to the server.  My forms work fine but the solution feels sloppy to me.

My current solution:
I set the stylesheet in the instance document & let the browser do the translation.  After the translation, I run Javascript from the form to load the XML document *again* into a Javascript var (an XML DOM).  To post the form data, I use Javascript to extract data from the HTML document (an HTML DOM), update the XML DOM, and POST with XMLHttpRequest.

My preferred solution:
To simplify and optimize, I would rather access the original XML DOM (the one that must have existed prior to translation) from the HTML document so that I don't have to load the XML instance document again.  It seems possible since I see the original XML doc when I "view source" from the browser.  I've searched both online & inside the browser with Firebug but have not found any magic just yet.

My question:
Does anyone know if Javascript can access the original XML DOM from a resulting HTML DOM after an XSLT stylesheet has been applied?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've no idea, but I think when the browser interprets the HTML code created via XSLT, the original XML is unavailable, at least from the HTML perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify your XSLT to keep a copy of source XML in XHTML output. To let arbitrary tags into XHTML, use the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436176/1872046).